# Debugging Maven dependencies

Tags: java, maven, debugging

The project "child", contains a java class:

```
package org.child;

public class Elaborate {

    public String getStr() {
    return "hello";
    }
}
```

And this pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.child</groupId>
    <artifactId>child</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


</project>
```

The project "parent" contains this java class:

```
import org.child.Elaborate;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


    Elaborate elaborate = new Elaborate();

    System.out.println(elaborate.getStr());
    }
}
```

And this pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.parent</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.child</groupId>
        <artifactId>child</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

I'm opening the two projects into two separate Intellij windows. What I'm trying to do is debugging on both sides.

However, if I run the application with the "parent", I can only debug the parent. If I put a breakpoint in the "child", the debugger doesn't stop there.

Any idea on how I can do?

Comment: Debugging with a dependency will require the source code. I don't know about IntelliJ, but I imagine the process is identical. You'd need to tell IntelliJ what source files correspond to 'child' and then you will be able to place break points.

Comment: Did you try with 2 projects opened in the same workspace in the same InteliJ? Let IntelliJ maven plugin to figure out if the *child* module is the source of the *parent* dependency. I guess it's like in Eclipse

Comment: Attach debugger icon then select process.

Comment: when you import code with maven it downloads to user directory /.m2

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue as you I think:

I have multiple maven packages, which are separate IntelliJ 'modules'.

In order to debug a maven 'dependency' load it as a 'module' into the main IntelliJ 'Project' window.

File > Project structure... > Project Settings > Modules

Add > Import Module

Now navigate to your previously setup maven package, and select that folder.

Select Import Module from External Module > Maven

And make sure ***Import Maven Projects Automatically*** is selected.

You should now see two 'modules' in the sidebar of your project. Setup a breakpoint in one of the dependency modules, and then Run > Debug your main module, and it should work as expected.

Comment: This works. After importing the source for the maven dependency as a module like @atlas_scoffed said, the next time you debug you'll hit breakpoints inside the original source `.java` files of the imported module and not the java generated from the `.class` files.